# Additional scopes for OAuth2 LinkedIn Sing In product

Tags: linkedin-api, openid

I have an app in LinkedIn Developers Service. I'd like to use Sign In with LinkedIn to let users create profiles in my app using their LinkedIn profiles.

I have an issue, that I'd like to load more users' info from their LinkedIn profiles (like headlines or about from **r_lightprofile** scope), but it seems, there is no proper product on LinkedIn Developers Products page (the only one I've found the **r_lightprofile** scope is **Conversions API** and I seem not to need this).

By now, my app has been vitrificated to use *Sign In with LinkedIn using OpenID* Connect product, so I can get users' photos, names, and email addresses (**openid**, **email**, **profile** scopes).

Any other scope is forbidden for my app.